# Find variance in a two-period model

Tags: variance, economics

I am currently reviewing in-depth materials from [Svensson (2007)](https://larseosvensson.se/files/papers/svensson-robust-control-made-simple.pdf) and trying to retrieve equation (2.6) myself. To put it simply, I have such equation:

$$\pi_{t+1} = \gamma \pi_{t} + \alpha x_{t} + \varepsilon_{t}$$

and a loss function got under the hypothesis that $$\mathbb{E}(\pi_{t}) = \mathbb{E}(x_{t}) = 0$$

Which is written as:

$$\mathcal{L}_{t} = \mathbb{E}[\pi_{t}^{2}] + \lambda\mathbb{E}[x_{t}^{2}] = \mathbb{V}[\pi_{t}] + \lambda \mathbb{V}[x_{t}]$$

I also know that we can state:

$$x_{t} = -f\pi_{t}$$

And thus the first equation rewrites as:

$$\pi_{t+1} = (\gamma - \alpha f)\pi_{t} + \varepsilon_{t}$$

My question is: how can we find that equation (2.6) ?

$$\mathbb{V}(\pi_{t}) = \frac{1}{1 - (\gamma - \alpha f)^{2}}\mathbb{V}(\varepsilon_{t})$$

Is there something I am missing on Variance fundamentals when it comes to a "2 times" problem ?

Comment: If that can help other people in their reflexions, I simply did not spot the AR(1) process being set up and thus this question brought the answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103405/prove-expression-for-variance-ar1